# Laravel - Take only Year from Date in Database

Tags: php, mysql, date, laravel-5.4

I having trouble taking a date and only getting the year of the date. My date is displayed and stored in my database as: `2014-09-07`. What I only want to take is the year of that date (which is 2014).

Here is my code for taking the dates from the database:

```
$year = DB::table('pets')->pluck('dates')->unique();
```

This picks out the each unique date from the column `dates`. This works perfectly and manages to display the full date without any trouble.

So far I have tried this: I managed to only get the year using  `selectRaw('substr(dates,1,4) as year')`. This gets resulted in: `{"year":"2014"}`. I could not get rid of the brackets and suppose it is in a wrong format?

Basically, I need help to only get the year from the date that is located in a mySQL database.

Comment: In pluck your field is dates but in selectRaw your field is launch. You select wrong field.

Comment: @HakanSOMEZ Oops, my mistake. Copied the wrong code. I have edited my question properly!

Comment: Is the result always like this or sometimes?

Comment: @HakanSONMEZ Yes the result is always like this. When I `foreach` the result in my Blade file or `echo` it, it gets returned as `{"year":"2014"}`.

Comment: So you know it is json you can use it like this in blade. `@php( $year =( json_decode($year, true) )['year']  )`

Comment: `DB::table('pets')->selectRaw('distinct year(dates) as year')->pluck('year')`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Thanks! That managed to solve my issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you use `get()` when you use `selectRaw()` and then encode json. So it includes field name. You should use `pluck()` if you get column or if you get a value you should use `value()`.

```
$year = DB::table('pets')->selectRaw('substr(dates,1,4) as dates')->pluck('dates')->unique();
```

**Or in blade**

```
@php( $year =( json_decode($year, true) )['year'] )
```

Comment: Ah. I see what I was doing wrong. This answer works as does Paul's.

Answer (score 1):

This may be late, but for learning purposes:
using the model approach you could do this.

```
Pets::pluck('dates')->map(function ($pet) {
    return $pet->format('Y');
})->unique();
```